# Event on table td

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I create Vue table component and i have items and columns.

```
    items: [
        {
            'id':'1',
            'title': '<input type="text">',
            'description': '<input type="text">',
            'price': '<input type="number">'
        },
        {
            'id':'2',
            'title': '<input type="text">',
            'description': '<input type="text">',
            'price': '<input type="number">'
        }
    ],
    columns: [ 'id', 'title', 'description', 'price']
```

And my template is

```
     <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index"> {{column}}</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
              <td v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn" v-html="item[column]"></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hove i bint v-on:keyup event only on price column? I want only price column have trigger calculate metod.

```
    methods: {
        calculate: function () {
          // to do...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `keyup` event bubbles, you could just add an event handler to the appropriate `<td>` elements.

```
<td 
    v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" 
    :key="indexColumn" 
    v-html="item[column]"
    v-on="column === 'price' ? {'keyup': calculate} : {}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

V-on:keyup should fire when a certain key is just released, for instance when you press enter: v-on:enter.
So, first, you need to specify a key. Secondly, how do you connect a key press event to a table column?

Maybe you just need a click event on that column -> v-on:click

Comment: I create metod that added new table row. And i want to automatic calculate all values in price columns. If you understand me. For example i have six row, i want to calculate all six price column when user stop typing in price column.

Comment: that's the perfected use case for a computed property, say: 

` totals () {
      return this.items.reduce((acc, curr) =>  acc + curr.price, 0)
    } `